# Is there any difference between using multiple if statements and else if statements?

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic

This question pertains specifically to shell scripts, but could be about any programming language.

Is there any difference between using multiple `if` statements and using `elif` statements in shell scripts? And, a `case` statement would not work in my situation.

Comment: This depends on the layout and interactions, naturally.

Comment: This question really should be [tag:language-agnostic].

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yes, potentially. Consider this (C#, Java, whatever):

```
int x = GetValueFromSomewhere();

if (x == 0)
{
    // Something
    x = 1;
}
else if (x == 1)
{
    // Something else...
}
```

vs this:

```
int x = GetValueFromSomewhere();

if (x == 0)
{
    // Something
    x = 1;
}
if (x == 1)
{
    // Something else...
}
```

In the first case, only *one* of "Something" or "Something else..." will occur. In the second case, the side-effects of the first block make the condition in the second block true.

Then for another example, the conditions may not be mutually exclusive to start with:

```
int x = ...;

if (x < 10)
{
    ...
} 
else if (x < 100)
{
    ...
}
else if (x < 1000)
{
    ...
}
```

If you get rid of the "else" here, then as soon as one condition has matched, the rest will too.

Comment: I think, if I write conditional statements in a function and write only if-statements and return inside still I should return something at the end of the function. But in the case of if-else statements, I don't need to return anything outside of if-else statements if I return inside the conditional statements. Am I right, what do you think?

Comment: @codosopher: Basically, you need to make sure that the compiler can tell that you'll *always* hit a return statement, without having to reason about the conditions themselves.

Answer (score 26):

It has to do with efficiency and your needs. `If` statements are executed independent of one another; each one will run. `Else if` statements only execute if the previous `if`s fail.

Answer (score 11):

```
if (x == 0) {
    // 1
}


if (x >= 0) {
    // 2
}

if (x <= 0) {
    // 3
}
```

Above code will produce different value than the code below for `x=0`.

```
if (x == 0) {
    // 1
} else if (x >= 0) {
    // 2
} else {
   // 3
}
```

In the first case all the statements `1`, `2`, and `3` will be executed for `x = 0`. In the second case only statements `1` will be.

Answer (score 4):

When you have multiple if statements, each is evaluated separately, and if the conditions are right, the code in all of them might be executed. If you have if / elif statement, the second condition would be evaluated only after particular result of the evaluation of the first condition.

Consider this pseudocode:

```
If (cond A) { action 1}
If (cond B) { action 2}
```

If both cond A and cond B are true, both actions will execute.

On the other hand, this pseudocode:

```
If (cond A) {action 1}
Elif (cond B) {action 2}
```

Only one of the two actions (or neither) will be executed, no matter how both conditions evaluate.

Answer (score -1):

I observed the following while solving [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/powx-n/):

[image: if-elif-elif-else]

[image: if-if-if-else]

Using `if-elif-else` takes up more memory, but executes faster (makes sense) than using multiple `if` statements.