# Is there a difference between multiple if statements and else if?

Tags: c, if-statement

If I write

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

if (a == b) {

//Do something

} else if (a > b) {

//Do something else

} else if (a < b) {

//Do something else

}
```

as opposed to:

```
if (a == b) {

//Do something

}
if (a > b) {

//Do something else

}
if (a < b) {

//Do something else

}
```

Is there a difference be it the way the compiler interprets the code or speed? I see no logical difference, but there surely must be a reason why an if else statement exists. It's just a single line break difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between using multiple if statements and else if statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636191/is-there-any-difference-between-using-multiple-if-statements-and-else-if-stateme)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the scenario above, they are the same, other than speed. `If`/`else` will be faster than a series of `if`s, because `else` statements are skipped if the `if` condition is satisfied. In a series of `if`s, on the other hand, each condition is evaluated separately.

In other scenarios, of course, the logic is not the same, and so replacing `if`/`else` with a series of `if`s breaks the program. Example:

```
// this:
if(x <= 0) {
    x = 1;
}
else { // only true if x started out > 0
    x = 37;
}

// is different from this:
if(x <= 0) {
    x = 1;
}
if(x > 0) { // always true in this version
    x = 37;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In  `else-if` statements, when a condition is met, all other `else-if`s are skipped.

Whereas in multiple if statements, it has to go through all of them.

To be more precise, Lets suppose `a=b`.

**Consider your first code block:**

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
if (a == b) 
{
    //Do something
} 
else if (a > b) 
{
    //Do something else
} 
else if (a < b) 
{
    //Do something else
}
```

While executing, since `a=b`, it will skip all other conditions (`a>b` & `a<b`).

1. Checks if `a=b`.
2. Executes the code block.
3. All others are skipped.

**Consider your second code block:**

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
if (a == b) 
{
     //Do something
}
if (a > b) 
{
    //Do something else
}
if (a < b) 
{
    //Do something else
}
```

Even the first condition is met, all of them will be evaluated.

1. Checks if `a=b`.
2. Executes the code block.
3. Checks if `a>b`.
4. Checks if `a<b`.

Comment: Does that improve speed?

Answer (score 0):

In second type of code you wrote. Compiler will show out put for each true statement and will not skip any condition. Else command is use to make sure that one of two conditions are matched.

Answer (score -1):

the time complexity of if-else statements is less as compared to  multiple if  statements. Therefore  if-else steements are much advantageous